# MVC: Display an input if two rows match in database using LINQ

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, razor

I am trying to hide that input if in database current logged user have already a Job posted on website, if UserID doesn't have anything added in database I want that input to be displayed/

At this point in View is displayed only that '< span >' no matter what.

```
        @{
            var db = new JobSite3.Models.ApplicationDbContext();   
            var controller = new JobSite3.Controllers.BaseController(); 
        }

        @if (db.Jobs.Where(x => x.UserID == controller.LoggedUserId).Select(x => x.ID) != null)
        {
            <span>No input</span>
        }
        else
        {
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-10">
                    <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        }
```

Comment: It might be because an empty collection is always different than null. Regardless of whether you find the user or not, that will return true.

Comment: Your query returns `IEnumerable<int>` (assuming `ID` is typeof `int`). It can never be null, just an empty collection. BUt your query makes no sense anyway (you have initialized a **new** `BaseController`) and code like that should never be in a view.

Comment: Yea, I am not really sure what I am trying to do in that if statement. I want to fetch the current logged user id with the one in database and see if this id have and ID from Jobs table. In BaseController is just `return User.Identity.GetUserId();` . Right now I am just trying everything comes up in my mind.

Comment: Put the query in the controller method that return this view. And then you can use a view model property (or `ViewBag` property) in the view - e.g. `@if (VIewBag.HasJobs) { .... } else { .... }`

Comment: How do I mark your answer as solution? Also I make an Answer with full solution in case someone needs too. I know is a bad habit to put Controller code on View, can you explain me why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per Stephen Muecke suggestions I made my code work and here is the solution in case someone needs too:

Controller:

```
    // GET: Jobs/Create
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
       var query = db.Jobs.Where(x => x.UserID == LoggedUserId).Select(x => x.ID.ToString()).Any();

       ViewBag.HasJobs = query;

       return View();

    }
```

View:

```
        @if (ViewBag.HasJobs != true)
        {
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-10">
                    <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
                </div>
            </div>
        }
        else
        {
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-10">
                    <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" disabled="disabled" />
                </div>
            </div>
        }
```

There isn't anymore a < span > but the last input have a disabled parameter, which was the first intention.